# Spring bean validation with hibernate annotation warning messages resolution

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a problem how messages are resolved using hibernate annotations in Spring forms.
I have following method in the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  CustResponse storeForm(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,
            @Valid @RequestBody Form form, BindingResult result) {
```

And when request comes I want to resolve all error messages into CustResponse object. In order to resolve warning message I am using following method from BindingResult result:

```
result.getCode();
```

According to documentation it:

> - Return the default code of this resolvable, that is,      * the last
>     one in the codes array.

And default code are is resolved is very general: NotBlank for this annotation:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
```

However it also exists other more specific error codes in the  BindingResult result. As example:
[NotBlank.form.fieldNAme, NotBlank.fieldNAme, NotBlank.java.lang.String, NotBlank]

And I think it makes more sense to resolve error message using most meaningful error code:
NotBlank.form.fieldNAme 
In order to resolve warning message I don't want to iterate through all error codes. 
How would you suggest to cope with such kind of issue ?

Comment: I wonder how you resolve the code. Or do you just return it as is?

Comment: I am using this API: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/DefaultMessageSourceResolvable.html#getCode()

Comment: Sure, but that gets you the code, not the message. By message I mean something like "The field name must not be blank". Or do you use the `spring:message`tag on the JSP? I understand your question but I don't understand why you need a code in the first place and who will do what with it. And that makes it difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: I am using custom resource bundle manager to get real message based on code and it's working properly. I don't using jsp tags because I need to return custom json with translated error message. The main problem that key is resolved to NotBlank and I can't get correct error message

Comment: I see. The problem with "most meaningful" is that it depends on the situation. I'm afraid you need to iterate. In my projects I settled on always adding a message to the annotation, like `@NotBlank(message = "Name must not be blank")` or `@NotBlank(message = "NotBlank.form.fieldName")` for i18n. That way I always get a perfect message without any hassle.

Comment: I am ok, that it depends on situation but on common sense I  would expect default message will be resolved as "most meaningful". Ok In any case you can post this comment as an answer and I'd accept it. Thanks